# Copy a 2D array to other 2D array that unknown size in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have a question about dynamic 2D array returning. That means I don't know size of returning 2D array (It depends on some condition). Let see my problem

```
N=3; 
A[N][5]={}//Given a 2D array
for i=1 to N
   x=random between 0 and 1
   k=1;
   while(k<N&&x>0.3)

    k++;
    B_i=A_k //Look like copy value of array A to array B at position k
```

My problem is that I don't know the value of k, it depends on `(k<N&&x>0.3)`. Hence, I cannot initial the array B. Could you suggest to me one way to do it? This is my code that I tried

```
int A[2][5] =
    {
        {1,8,12,20,25},
        {5,9,13,24,26},
        {15,1,5,2,22}
    };


int N=3;
   for(int i=0;i<N;i++) 
   {
   double x=random();//create random number between 0 and 1.
   int k=0;
   while(k<N&&x>0.3)
     {
     k++;
     B[k][4]=A[i][4]; //I have no idea to initial 2D array B
     }
   }
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, or better yet, a small wrapper class around an `std::vector<int>` of which `operator[]` does the index computation based on the logical dimensions of the array.

Comment: Could you see my code and the algorithm, then modify help me. I have no expert in vector class

Comment: What is the purpose of your while loop?

Comment: It increases the k. and copy the value of vector A to B. if satisfy this condition

Comment: @user8430: Then you have forgotten the braces. Currently you are only increasing k, but you don't perform any copying inside the loop.

Comment: Yes. I found it. Actually, This is Roulette wheel selection algorithm. Please see my update and Is my correct? Thanks

Comment: @user8430 - are you sure that your problem is about array dimension? It looks to me as if A and B should have the same dimension. In your code you should do  1) `int k = 0;` instaed of `int k=1;`and 2) move `k++;`below the assignment to array B. Moving k++ ensures that A and B can have the same dimension as the maximum k value when used for indexing will be N-1

Comment: Right. Index in C and C++ must be from 1. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

you may use

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> B;
st::vector<int> row;
row.push_back(1);
row.push_back(2);
B.push_bak(row);

st::vector<int> row1;
row1.push_back(3);
row1.push_back(4);
B.push_bak(row1);
```

in this way you will get array {{1,2},{3,4}}
or

```
int** B;
B = new int*[2];
B[0]=new int[2];
B[1]=new int[2];

B[0][0] =1;
B[0][1] =2;
B[1][0] =3;
B[1][1] =4;
```

Comment: How to copy directly value from vector A to B. Let see my question

Comment: A is not a vector in your code; I don't understand, what problem is. Do you want to assign B[k]=A[i]?

Comment: Sorry. Because someone suggest to me using vector. Hence, we can change A from array to vector. Then use it

Comment: I think that user8264 helped you,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the fact k can not become larger than N?

The loop

```
while(k<N && x>0.3)
 k++;
```

will always terminate when/if k becomes equal to N (regardless of x) so the array B should be

```
int B[N+1][5];
```

EDIT:
Just to clarify - the point is that k will alway be in the range [1..N]. I didn't want to state that k would always become N. Only that k could not be greater than N.

Comment: I think you are wrong, if x is not greater than 0.3, k will stay 1.

Comment: @MikeMB - I wrote "when/if" to indicate that k can be less than N. The point is, however, that k can not be greater than N. Consequently `int B[N+1][5]`is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector< vector<int> > A;    
int N=3;
   for(int i=0;i<N;i++) 
   {
   double x=random();//create random number between 0 and 1.
   int k=1;
   while(k<N&&x>0.3)
     k++;
   B.push_back(A[i]);
   }
```

Comment: @user8261 - the code here is nothing like the OPs code. Your code never uses variable k. This again means that the calculation of k is unnecessary and thereby that the random value x isn't used either. In the end all your code does is to copy of A to B. Row-by-row. No random shuffling.

Comment: K is used for condition in while. B only copies the value of vector row A when it satisfies that condition.

Comment: @8430 - In the code provided in this answer by user8264, k is not used at all. `B.push_back(A[i]);` is independent of k.